# layout problem of multiple heatmaps in one figure with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I put multiple heatmaps in one figure with matplotlib. I cannot layout it well. Here is my code.

```py
import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(6,240,240)
y = np.random.rand(6,240,240)
t = np.random.rand(6,240,240)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.2, hspace=0.3)
c=1
for i in range(6):
  ax=plt.subplot(6,3,c)
  plt.imshow(x[i])
  ax.set_title("x"+str(i))
  c+=1
  ax=plt.subplot(6,3,c)
  plt.imshow(y[i])
  ax.set_title("y"+str(i))
  c+=1
  ax=plt.subplot(6,3,c)
  plt.imshow(t[i])
  ax.set_title("t"+str(i))
  c+=1
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("test.png")
```

test.png looks like this.
[image]

I want to

- make each heatmap bigger
- reduce the margin between each heatmaps in row.

I tried to adjust by "subplots_adjust", but it doesn't work.

## Additional information

According to  ImportanceOfBeingErnest's comment, I removed `tight_layout()`. It generated this.

[image]
It makes bigger each heatmap, but titles overlappes on subplots. And I still want to make each heatmap more bigger, and I want to reduce the margin in row.

Comment: Remove `plt.tight_layout()` or at least call `subplots_adjust` after that.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I added information above. `tight_layout()` seems to be needed to prevent overlapping.

Comment: Yeah, but now you can play with `hspace` and until you're satisfied with the result. Here, probably something like `hspace=1` or higher is needed. For the spacings in the rows, use higher `left` and lower `right` parameter. Most probably you also want to change the figure size.

Comment: You should increase the height of the figure.